# Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object. mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-update

This is my php code:

```
include ("dbinfo.php");

if(isset($_POST['editsave'])){
$edittitle=$_POST["edittitle"];
$editurl=$_POST["editurl"];
$editdesc=$_POST["editdesc"];
$editid=$_POST["editid"];

$mysqli = $GLOBALS['dbc'];
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE links SET title = ?, 
  \desc = ? 
  WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('ssd',
  $_POST['edittitle'],
  $_POST['editdesc'],
  $_POST['editid']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
}
```

This is my form:

```
    <form role="form" action="edit.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="title">Title</label>
      <input type="text" name="edittitle" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Enter title" maxlength="70" value="<?php echo ($title); ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="url">URL</label>
      <input type="text" name="editurl" class="form-control" id="url" value="<?php echo ($url); ?>" disabled>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="desc">Description</label><small> (max 500 characters)</small>
      <textarea class="form-control" name="editdesc" id="desc" rows="5" maxlength="500"><?php echo ($desc); ?></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="hidden" name="editid" value="<? echo $id; ?>">
      <button type="submit" name="editsave" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

When i press submit i get this:

Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /storage/content/x/xxx/ on line 27.

Line 27 is:

```
$stmt->bind_param('ssd',
```

I'm not familiar with mysqli. I have tried to fix the problem for a few days now and I'm getting crazy.

Comment: what is the type of your id field in database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that the query inside [mysqli::prepare()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) resulted in an error.

According to the doc:

> mysqli_prepare() returns a statement object or FALSE if an error occurred.

Try to properly escape `desc`, which is a reserved keyword in MySQL (`\` is not proper escaping):

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE links SET title = ?, `desc` = ? WHERE id = ?');
```

Comment: @YourCommonSense My mistake, the doc says indeed *Unlike some other languages, backticks cannot be used within double-quoted strings*. Removed this statement from my answer. Thank you.